# How do I change the PIN on an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sim

A simple one, I guess:

I recently bought a new (unlocked) iPhone, and at the same time changed my phone subscription to another operator. **How can I set the PIN code on the new SIM card** to something other than the default? With a quick look, I couldn't find anything related in iPhone settings.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can find the option under Settings > Phone > SIM PIN.

Comment: Ah, I somehow overlooked that. I guess "Phone" was just too obvious. :)

Comment: The **SIM PIN** option wasn't under Phone, but **Mobile Data**, like the answer blow suggests (might have changed since 2010)

Answer (score 5):

The setting to change SIM PIN can be found under Settings app → Mobile Data → SIM PIN and not under Settings app → Phone.